# Parsing table with streaks of binaries to select larger group element

Tags: python-3.x

I have a table like the following (only much longer):

```
#    time    binary    frequency

0     2.1      0         0.65
1     3.2      1         0.72
2     5.8      0         0.64
3     7.1      0         0.63
4     9.5      1         0.72
5     14.1     1         0.74
6     21.5     0         0.62
7     27.3     0         0.61
8     29.5     1         1.00
9     32.1     1         1.12
10    35.5     1         0.99
```

I want to collect all the `times` correspondent to only `binary == 1` and, among the small groups, those whose correspondent `frequency` value is higher. In the table above, this would result in:

```
times = 3.2, 14.1, 32.1
```

I am not sure how to approach the sequentiality of the table on the first place, and then how to compare the values among them returning only the correspondent time (and not, for example, the largest frequency). Time hides a periodicity, so I would avoid to build another table with only `binary == 1` elements.

Having my `time`, `binary`, and `frequency` arrays, I can isolate relevant elements by:

```
condition = (binary == 1)
time1 = time(condition)
frequency1 = frequency(condition)
```

but I do not know how to proceed to isolate the various streaks. What are useful functions I can use?

Answer (score 2):

I don't know that there are any clever functions to use for this. Here's some code that will do the job. Please note that I removed the headers from your file.

`binary` is either zero or one, depending on whether the rows other values are to be included in a group. Initially `in_group` is set to `False` to indicate that no group has started. As rows are read, when `binary` is zero, if the code has been reading rows for a group and, therefore, `in_group` is True, `in_group` is set to `False` because now that a zero has been encountered that group has come to an end. Since processing of the group has ended, it's time to print results for it. As rows are read, when `binary` is one, if `in_group` is True then the code has already started processing rows are a group and the code checks whether the newest `frequency` is greater than what has been see before. If so, it updates both `rep_time` and `rep_frequency`. If `in_group` is False then this is the first row of a new group and `in_group` is set True and initial values of `rep_time` and `rep_frequency` are set.

```
with open('pyser.txt') as pyser:
    in_group = False
    for line in pyser:
        _, time, binary, frequency = [float(_) for _ in line.rstrip().split()]
        if binary == 0:
            if in_group:
                in_group = False
                print (rep_time)
        else:
            if in_group:
                if frequency > rep_frequency:
                    rep_time, rep_frequency = time, frequency 
            else:
                in_group = True
                rep_time, rep_frequency = time, frequency 
if in_group:
    print (rep_time)
```

Output:

```
3.2
14.1
32.1
```

Edit: We seem to be using different definitions of the problem.

[image: sample]

In the first group, we agree. But, in the second group, the maximum amplitude is about 4.07E-01, which corresponds to a time of about 5.4740E+04.

I've also written code in Pandas:

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> df = pd.read_csv('Gyd9P1rb.txt', sep='\s+', skiprows=2, header=None, names='Row TSTOP PSRTIME DETECTED FDOTMAX AMPLITUDE AMPLITUDE_ERR'.split())
>>> del df['Row']
>>> del df['TSTOP']
>>> del df['FDOTMAX']
>>> del df['AMPLITUDE_ERR']
>>> groups = []
>>> in_group = False
>>> group_number = 1
>>> for b in df['DETECTED']:
...     if b:
...         if not in_group:
...             group_number +=1
...             in_group = True
...         groups.append(group_number)
...     else:
...         groups.append(0)
...         in_group = False
... 

>>> df['groups'] = pd.Series(groups, index=df.index)
>>> df.head()
        PSRTIME  DETECTED  AMPLITUDE  groups
0  54695.471283         1   0.466410       2
1  54698.532412         1   0.389607       2
2  54701.520814         1   0.252858       2
3  54704.557583         0   0.103460       0
4  54707.557563         0   0.088215       0
>>> gb = df.groupby(by=df['groups'])
>>> def f(x):
...     the_max = x['AMPLITUDE'].idxmax()
...     print ( x['groups'][the_max], x['PSRTIME'][the_max])
... 
>>> gb.apply(f)
0 58064.3656376
0 58064.3656376
2 54695.4712834
3 54740.4917137
4 54788.477571
5 54836.472922
6 54881.4605511
7 54926.4664883
8 54971.4932866
9 55019.5021472
10 55064.5029133
11 55109.4948108
12 55154.414381
13 55202.488766
14 55247.4721132
15 55292.5301332
16 55340.4728542
17 55385.5229596
18 55430.5332147
19 55478.4812671
20 55523.4894451
21 55568.4626766
22 55616.4630348
23 55661.4969604
24 55709.4504634
25 55754.4711994
26 55799.4736923
27 55844.5050404
28 55892.4699313
29 55937.4721754
30 55985.4677572
31 56030.5119765
32 56075.5517149
33 56168.4447074
34 56213.507484
35 56306.5133063
36 56351.4943058
37 56396.579122
38 56441.5683651
39 56489.5321173
40 56534.4838082
41 56582.469025
42 56627.4135202
43 56672.4926625
44 56720.582296
45 56768.5232469
46 56813.4997925
47 56858.3890558
48 56903.5182596
49 56951.4892721
50 56996.5787435
51 57086.3948136
52 57179.5421833
53 57272.5059448
54 57362.452523
55 57635.5013047
56 57728.4925251
57 57773.5235416
58 57821.5390364
59 57866.5205882
60 57911.5590132
61 57956.5699637
62 58001.4331976
Empty DataFrame
Columns: []
Index: []
```

The results of the two methods are the same, up to differences in presentation precision.

I also created a small set of data that would give easily calculable results. This is it. The original program performed correctly.

```
0 -1 0 -1
1 0 1 2
2 -1 0 -1
3 -1 0 -1
4 0 1 0
5 1 1 1
6 -1 0 -1
7 -1 0 -1
8 -1 0 -1
9 0 1 4
10 1 1 3
11 2 1 2
12 -1 0 -1
13 -1 0 -1
14 -1 0 -1
15 -1 0 -1
16 0 1 0
17 1 1 1
18 2 1 2
19 3 1 3
20 -1 0 -1
21 -1 0 -1
22 -1 0 -1
23 -1 0 -1
24 -1 0 -1
25 0 1 6
26 1 1 5
27 2 1 4
28 3 1 3
29 4 1 2
30 -1 0 -1
31 -1 0 -1
32 -1 0 -1
33 -1 0 -1
34 -1 0 -1
35 -1 0 -1
36 0 1 0
37 1 1 1
38 2 1 2
39 3 1 3
40 4 1 4
41 5 1 5
41 -1 0 -1
41 -1 0 -1
```

Comment: Thank you! So you decided to parse by lines and not by row, I guess it has sense... Could you please comment the code a bit? Especially the `if in_group:` is not very clear to me.

Comment: Also, there is something wrong: it gives back a number of `times` that is much more than expected. This means that it probably counts for more `times` at time (it assignes more than just one `time` to each `binary==1` sub-group).

Comment: @Py-ser: Sorry! Would you please post a bigger sample of your data somewhere.

Comment: @Py-ser: ... and give me the results you would expect for that sample.

Comment: Here is an example of data https://pastebin.com/Gyd9P1rb. What I expect is a list of times correspondent to the local maximum `amplitude` (where "local" means the sub-group of `detections == 1`): `times = 5.469547128344E+04, 5.473746894780E+04, 5.478847757096E+04, 5.483948119222E+04, 5.487547385719E+04` and so on

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/161745/discussion-between-py-ser-and-bill-bell).